# Pulling first win information

Tags: riot-games-api

I am looking to pull first win information (time first win is available) for a summoner in League of Legends; I can't seem to find a way to pull this specific info anywhere in RIOT games API and I went through the [full API reference](https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/1091). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an endpoint for this currently. However, here is something related: [First Win App on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pronind.firstwinoftheday&hl=en). Presumably the developer there worked out a way to calculate it - my guess is you could do the same. You'd need to get a players IP gains from wins (not sure how you'd account for IP boosts of any sort), and find the last match in their match history with a significant IP gain (pick something greater than the max you can expect in a normal game, maybe 200?).